# Why do CMS sites exist?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is there a reason why CMS-scoped sites, like [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/), [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), [Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) and [Craft CMS](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/), are not folded into Stack Overflow, Server Fault, etc.?

These sites seem to cover areas that are already covered more broadly by other sites.

Comment: I'm a bit out of the loop. What does CMS stand for?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Content Management System - such as WordPress, etc.

Comment: What sites, for example?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens The OP specifically mentions CMS-scoped sites in his post, and all those edited in serve as good examples of precisely that. Well within the rules, no need to be nitpicky.

Comment: @Seth Merci for explaining such kinds of rules. I assume then Joomla.SE also fits, no?

Comment: Also, SO gets 8100 questions/day. That's over twice as much as *every other site on the network, combined*. The next highest site gets 660. The real question is why hasn't SO split into 10 or 20 different new sites yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Configuring a CMS can hardly be seen as programming  or professional server administration. Hence those CMS sites fill a gap which is left by the other sites.

Of course, some questions about CMS systems are on-topic on the sites mentioned, but only within their specific scope, like programming for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, CMS-specific sites are generally created out of <quote> [...an ecosystem of questions that are not already in scope on the existing site(s)](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17837/apparently-this-is-a-duplicate/17846#17846).