# Inconsistent response on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, vote-to-close, off-topic

I have started using Stack Exchange websites regularly recently and Stack Overflow very often since I am programmer.

I see that the responses are very inconsistent. Inconsistent in the sense that some of the questions in the same topic were answered with both questions and answers getting many upvotes but some of the questions of the same topic has been closed within minutes after posting with downvotes as well.

**Scenario 1**:
This question, "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799912/does-icici-payment-gateway-validate-sales-tax-percentage-during-payment" has been closed as off-topic within few minutes after it is been posted but I can see that similar questions has been answered with many upvotes like here: "[Building a complete online payment gateway like Paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647430/building-a-complete-online-payment-gateway-like-paypal)" which looks like opinion based question. Both the Askers are trying to get a solution for their requirement but they have been handled very differently.

**Scenario 2**:
I have seen lots of questions related to WordPress (but not programming) answered by many and received many upvotes. But I have also seen a few WordPress questions closed with a note to post the question in WordPress Stack Exchange website. If we have a separate website for WordPress then why should we have tags related to WordPress" in Stack Overflow? The same applies to Magento and Drupal as well.

I am not complaining but I was not sure how it works and I am still trying to learn how it works. I personally think like, it is largely based on the character and mood of the first few guys who Answer. If this question was not closed, then first question could have get few Answers which could have helped the Asker. By the way the Asker of the first question happened to be me.

Comment: compare the dates on those two questions, Stack Overflow today is a very different site than Stack Overflow 7 years ago.

Comment: Yes, I agree @MadScientist. But these questions are not related to programming but got few answers which could have helped the OP a bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476895/payment-method-check-money-order-is-not-displaying-in-checkout-page, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476895/payment-method-check-money-order-is-not-displaying-in-checkout-page, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731693/authorize-net-the-underlying-connection-was-closed . And the 2nd scenario still applies

Comment: Inconsistency is going to happen. The site is too big and requires far too many eyes to fully enforce the rules/regulations/scope. And most eyes that see certain content won't exactly be aware of what's considered on/off-topic. They'll just see something they like or dislike. If you want the site to be more consistent, try to establish what the consensus is for certain types of posts, and help us enforce it.

Comment: You'll note that now you've brought that second question to light, it has been quickly closed.

Comment: @ale, sorry I didn't get your point clearly, Can you please explain?

Comment: @manian: The [2nd question you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2647430) is now closed. The reason it wasn't closed before now is because no one really noticed it before now. Since you've pointed it out, at least five people went to see it, saw that it is off-topic by today's standards, and voted to close. That's why you often cannot rely on an old question to guide you as to what is currently on-topic.

Comment: Ah ok. Got it now, thanks @ale for explaining. I think this is one possible answer to the question. Getting to know better about SO slowly now

Answer (score 2):

It's worth remembering that SE relies a lot on *metamoderation*. Essentially, as people gain reputation, they get abilities closer to that of a full moderator and close things.

One of the odd consequences of it is "what's acceptable" often changes over time. Its not *really* worth the effort to hunt these down and close them, so we tend to handle them as people notice. Sites evolve organically, and more recent questions are always a better sign of what's acceptable.

When I'm new to a site, I like to rely on the on-topic and off-topic help pages to see what's explicitly on- or off-topic (which would have probably suggested this question might not be on topic) and try to play it safe until I *got* the site.

To me the *big* problem with the question is that its really about "business rules" so to speak, and ICICI's support or representatives would be the best people to answer it - as the comments say.

While I don't use SO much - to me, *any* SO question should revolve around *my* code (should I write any) rather than something purely at an API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario #1:** As already pointed out in the comments, the upvoted question was asked **7 years ago**. Since then, policies, the community consensus regarding those questions as well as the scope of the site have shifted.

Whilst it was allowed and well-received to ask a question about a book-recommendation back in the day, doing so nowadays will most likely (*unless you manage to dodge about everyone and everything watching out for those questions*) earn you a question that's downvoted and closed as `Primarily opinion-based [POB]`.

**Scenario #2:** This was already asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295580/why-do-cms-sites-exist). The main reason is that CMS-related questions are **mostly** off-topic for Stack Overflow, as they're all-too-often not about programming, however, some WP-questions are about programming, and as such on-topic for Stack Overflow.

---

In general, before asking a question, one should ensure that it is in fact on-topic (*maybe search for similar questions and see how they were received, if posted rather recently*), and also ensure that your question is complete. [Here's a list of criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), and here are help center articles regarding [the topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [the types](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) of questions that you should/shouldn't ask.

Additionally, if you have a lot of time to spare, it also never hurts to visit [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and search for discussions that deal with the type of question that you want to ask. This is a very efficient method if you want to predict the reaction of the community, as the community consensus (*agreement of the community on how to handle certain things*) is often a result of a meta discussion.

---

Last but not least: I dearly hope that no one takes offense at bad English skills. That'd be rather weird, as we have the `Edit`-option available to us for that specific reason.